# Label no Grafico de Pizza

Tags: delphi

Estou criando um Grafico de Pizza em Runtime.
Desejo ter um TLabel no centro de cada fatia do grafico com um valor, porém ao criar a Label todos ficam alinhados no centro do circle que serve de base.

Mesmo o Label tendo seu Parent bem definido como TPie. E por sua vez o TPie tem seu Parent o Circle onde seu objetivo funciona perfeitamente;
Esse codigo foi compilado no Delphi 12 Athenas.

Segue exemplo do codigo:

```
procedure TFRelLocacoes.GraficoPizza(valorini,valorfim, cor: integer);
var
    Pie: TPie;
    Etiqueta: TLabel;
begin

    Pie := TPie.Create(Circle);
    Etiqueta:= TLabel.Create(nil);
    Etiqueta.Text:= IntToStr(valorfim);
    Etiqueta.TextSettings.Font.Family:= 'Arial';
    Etiqueta.TextSettings.FontColor:= TAlphaColorRec.Black;
    Etiqueta.TextSettings.Font.Style:= [TFontStyle.fsBold];
    Pie.Parent:= Circle;
    Pie.Align:= TAlignLayout.Center;
    Etiqueta.Parent:= Pie;
    Etiqueta.Align:= TAlignLayout.Center;
    Etiqueta.TextAlign:= TTextAlign.Center;
    Pie.Height:= 257;
    Pie.Width:=257;
    Pie.Fill.Color:= cor;
    Pie.Stroke.Color:= cor;
    Pie.StartAngle:=valorini;
    Pie.RotationAngle:= -90;
    Pie.EndAngle:= valorfim;



end;
```